# Mitsubishi Colt splutters in when engine is cold

Tags: mitsubishi, cold-start, colt

I have a 3-door Mitsubishi Colt '99 model hatchback.

Just a couple of questions I'd like to ask..

First of all when I leave my car parked up for the night and then I go to drive it in the morning it seems like my car has lost power.  It starts fine but struggles and if i drive straight away I put my foot down to drive and it splutters.

I thought of many things I changed my manifold and I got whole new exhaust fitted because I thought it might be losing power through them but it still does this every day..

But after about ten minutes of driving the car of spluttering it stops then..  I need a solution I need to know what is wrong with my car..

Can someone help? Sorry for long essay but no shorter way I could have put it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a bad coolant temperature sensor. It tells the ECU (Electronic Control Unit) if the coolant is hot or cold so it can adjust the mixture through the fuel injection system.

A bad CTS will give the ECU incorrect readings and the mixture will not be matched to the temperature of the vehicle.  Fuel mixture settings are very dependent upon temperature.

Its an easy and cheap fix on your car. The sensor is located near the thermostat housing. You can do it yourself.

Edit to add picture:

[Housing assembly](http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/3dAAAOSwbqpTyDyI/s-l1600.jpg)

Part is black plastic bit protruding on the bottom left. This part is located on the driver's side of the vehicle. A radiator hose is connected to it.

Comment: could you find an image or something to denote the location for the OP?

Comment: @DucatiKiller Done. =)

Comment: Upvote for quality, thanks.  good to have you around.